# Console is bigger than my Raspberry Pi screen resolution

Tags: touchscreen, screen, terminal

I have bought a Raspberry Pi 7" touch screen, and it seems to work fine.

When the boot process is running, the normal Linux boot messages appear on the screen - but after the screen is filled, it seems to continue to write below the screen. As if the screen is "underscanned".

The `LINES` environment variable says `LINES=48`. Counting the number of lines visible on screen, I get to 30.

Values in `/boot/config.txt`:

```
lcd_rotate=2
disable_overscan=1
dtparam=i2c_arm=off
dtparam=audio=on
enable_uart=0
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
```

Values in `/etc/default/console-setup`:

```
ACTIVE_CONSOLES="/dev/tty[1-6]"
CHARMAP="UTF-8"
CODESET="guess"
FONTFACE="Terminus"
FONTSIZE="8x16"
VIDEOMODE=
```

What should I do?

The screen resolution is 800x480. The problem does not go away after the boot process. I have to type `stty rows 30` to make it look okay.

Comment: What is your screen resolution and how are things after the boot process completes

Comment: @MohammadAli The screen resolution is 800x480. The problem does not go away after the boot process. I have to type `stty rows 30` to make it look okay.

Comment: But in another full screen program do you have this problem? Or is it unique to the console?

Comment: @MohammadAli It is only in the console. When I start X, the screen size seem right.

Comment: The screen may seem right when it is not, can you test it by running something like scratch or the web browser in full screen